# Double to string alternative due to performance issue

Tags: java, performance

Need help finding an alternative. This is the current code that I'm running on an environment. Looks like it affects the performance of my application and is not fast enough. I'm thinking of the try-catch method. Will it work or is there a better alternative you can suggest to convert a double to a string?

```
public static String formatDoubleValue(String string) {

    if (string == null)
        return null;

    if (string.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)")) {
        //System.out.println(string + " is a Double");
        Double dVal = Double.parseDouble(string);
        //System.out.println("Formatted value: " + NUM_FORMAT.format(dVal));
        return NUM_FORMAT.format(dVal);
    } else {
        //System.out.println(string + " is not a Double");
        return string;
    }
}

public static String formatDoubleValuesixdigit(String string) {

    if (string == null)
        return null;

    if (string.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)")) {
        //System.out.println(string + " is a Double");
        Double dVal = Double.parseDouble(string);
        //System.out.println("Formatted value: " + NUM_FORMAT.format(dVal));
        return NUM_FORMAT_SIXDIGIT.format(dVal);
    } else {
        //System.out.println(string + " is not a Double");
        return string;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. :)    One way to improve the performance of this is to skip the pattern-matching and just parse your string - you're doing that anyway, you can just skip the (slow) pattern-matching.

Comment: In addition to the suggestions everyone else is making, https://github.com/ulfjack/ryu contains a faster algorithm for formatting doubles to strings than what Java has.

Comment: Note that you should take care with (presumably) `NumberFormat` instances in static fields. `NumberFormat` etc aren't thread-safe. Consider using a `ThreadLocal`.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to propose an alternative, because we don't know exactly how you want the numbers formatted.

However, every time you execute this line:

```
if (string.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)")) {
```

you are recompiling a regular expression. That's going to be reasonably slow.

Compile it once, store in a field:

```
static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)");
```

and then use this in the condition:

```
if (PATTERN.matcher(string).matches()) {
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `Scanner` over the `String` *might* give you better performance, like

```
public static String formatDoubleValuesixdigit(String string) {
    if (string != null) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(string);
        if (sc.hasNextDouble()) {
            return NUM_FORMAT_SIXDIGIT.format(sc.nextDouble());
        }
    }
    return string;
}
```

and

```
public static String formatDoubleValue(String string) {
    if (string != null) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(string);
        if (sc.hasNextDouble()) {
            return NUM_FORMAT.format(sc.nextDouble());
        }
    }
    return string;
}
```